# I just want to modify the array which will give only numbers(numbers may be decimal ) ,how to remove characters other than number from array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
myArray = ['1 in','2 in', '3 in']
```

expected output=

```js
['1','2','3']
```

but if we add we should able to type ","

I have tried `trim`, `split`, `paresfloat`, `filter` methods but it's not working.

Comment: `myArray.map(n => n.replace( /[^\d.]+/g, ''))`

Comment: You can use this code:-

`var myArray = ['1 in','2 in', '3 in']
var newAr = myArray.map((element)=>{ return element.replace(/\D/g , ''); });`

Comment: @Dotsquares `'1.9 in'` will fail

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```js
let arr = ["1 in" , "2 in", "3 in"]
let filteredArray = arr.map((elt)=>elt.replace( /(?!-)[^0-9.]/g, ""))
console.log(filteredArray)
```